# Custom design of spinner in Android

Tags: android, android-spinner

I would like to ask, if there is a way, how to create a spinner element with custom design. I need spinner with more than one assorted elements like on the picture:

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: What definitely you need?

Answer (score 0):

Make a custom LinearLayout and set a click listner on linear layout open a dialog having listview and implements BaseAdapter to show items in listview like below

Below is method to open dialog on linear layout click 
Dialog:

```
public void showNatureEnquiryList() {
        final Dialog dialog1 = new Dialog(ContactUsActivity.this);
        dialog1.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog1.setContentView(R.layout.nature_of_query_layout);

        ListView stringListView = (ListView) dialog1
                .findViewById(R.id.listview_nature_of_enquiry_listiview);
        final ArrayList<NatureOfEnquiry> stringList = new ArrayList<NatureOfEnquiry>();
        stringList.add(new NatureOfEnquiry("Prequalify Now"));
        stringList.add(new NatureOfEnquiry("Bond Enquiry"));
        stringList.add(new NatureOfEnquiry("Insurance Enquiry"));
        stringList.add(new NatureOfEnquiry("General"));

        NatureOfEnquiryBaseAdapter adapter = new NatureOfEnquiryBaseAdapter(
                ContactUsActivity.this, stringList);
        stringListView.setAdapter(adapter);

        stringListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                natureOfEnquiryTextView.setText(stringList.get(position).listString);
                messagesEditText.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
                messagesEditText.requestFocus();
                dialog1.dismiss();              
            }

        });

        dialog1.show();

        dialog1.setOnDismissListener(new OnDismissListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
                messagesEditText.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        messagesEditText.requestFocusFromTouch();
                        InputMethodManager lManager = (InputMethodManager) ContactUsActivity.this
                                .getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                        lManager.showSoftInput(messagesEditText, 0);
                    }
                });

            }
        });

    }
```

Implementation of BaseAdapter Class:

```
public class NatureOfEnquiryBaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    Context context;
    ArrayList<NatureOfEnquiry> stringList;
    LayoutInflater inflater;

    public NatureOfEnquiryBaseAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<NatureOfEnquiry> stringList){
        this.context = context;
        this.stringList = stringList;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        if(stringList == null || stringList.size() == 0){
            return 0;
        }
        return stringList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return stringList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.nature_of_query_items,
                    parent, false);         
        }

        TextView text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textview_nature_of_query_text);

        text.setText(stringList.get(position).listString);

        return convertView;
    }

}
```